Dynamic Sumifs across several columns adding some and skipping some
I have a budget from Jan to Dec, populated with monthly figures for different business units and different business functions (although some business functions are the same). However, when creating a monthly P+L where I'd like to compare ACT vs BGT, I'd like to have the flexibility of obtaining the YTD total of a specific budget line by business unit & function depending on the month we are in.
I could use the following formula, but I am looking for something shorter and lighter as the formula has to be used in several other cells other than just on the dashboard. This is so that the excel workbook does not become heavy and bloated.
<=+IF(AND(C23="Apr",B23="ZWE | Maintenance")=TRUE,+SUMIFS(C3:C19,B3:B19,B24,A3:A19,B23)+SUMIFS(D3:D19,B3:B19,B24,A3:A19,B23)+SUMIFS(E3:E19,B3:B19,B24,A3:A19,B23)+SUMIFS(F3:F19,B3:B19,B24,A3:A19,B23),"")>

In another post on this forum, the below function would work beautifully but I do not know to add another sum field
Excel Sumifs with dynamic columns
This is the formula used in the post
=F3:F6, LAMBDA(x,SUM(XLOOKUP(G1,): XLOOKUP (I1, B2:D2, B3:D6) *(x=A3:A6))))
In my case, I'd like the BYROW (F3:F6... portion to be for my two conditions, i.e.,
"ZWE | Maintenance" & "Maintenance | Cleaning", and IF possible, the ability to add a third condition as well. What formula could I use?



Business Unit
Business Activity
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr




ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - Back-Charging
27
27
27
25


ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - Check Out
52,437
52,785
52,344
49,085


ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - Cleaning
84,059
84,616
83,909
78,685


ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - House Keeping
138,763
139,682
138,516
129,892


ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - Manpower
3,865
3,891
3,858
3,618


ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - Marble Cleaning
2,101,339
2,115,262
2,097,603
1,967,009


ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - MEP
4,797
4,829
4,789
4,490


ZWE - Maintenance
Maintenance - Pest Control
37,643
37,892
37,576
35,237


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - Back-Charging
53,078
53,430
52,984
49,685


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - Check Out
1,230,497
1,238,650
1,228,310
1,151,837


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - Cleaning
5,419
5,455
5,410
5,073


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - House Keeping
2,009
2,023
2,006
1,881


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - Manpower
496
499
495
464


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - Marble Cleaning
4,978
5,011
4,969
4,660


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - MEP
3,396,485
3,418,989
3,390,448
3,179,362


RSA - Maintenance
Maintenance - Pest Control
16,539
16,649
16,510
15,482




Post data as text table so that we can copy and work on those.

Use FILTER() and SUM().

@Harun24hr - I have updated the post with the table.

Note using volatile functions like OFFSET() and INDIRECT() will not only slow down the working functionality of Excel as well as it will always keep recalculating whenever there is a change in any open workbook. Beware of that fact. !!!

This formula works in traditional versions e.g. Excel 2013. The formula must be confirmed as an arrayformula with ctrl+shift+enter if someone doesn't work with Office 365 or Excel for the web or Excel 2021.
=SUM(OFFSET(C1:F1,MATCH(1,(A2:A17=B21)* 
(B2:B17=B22),0),0,1,MATCH(C21,C1:F1,0)))



Use nested FILTER() then SUM().
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C2:F17,C1:F1=J6),(A2:A17=I6)*(B2:B17=I7)))



Harun24hr & Mayukh
Thank you for your inputs, I understand your formulas will give the exact figure for April, however what I am looking for is a formula that when I choose Apr as reporting period, the formula will add Jan, Feb, Mar & Apr giving me 331,269.
If I am to choose Mar, it'll calc from Jan - Mar giving me 252,584.
I'm not sure if we can expand and extend from this formula from this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163830/excel-sumifs-with-dynamic-columns
In my query, its not only the columns that are dynamic, but also the rows.

@KudaMagaya Then use true date in heading like 01-Jan-2024, 01-Feb-2024 .... and try this formula =SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C2:F17,C1:F1<=J6),(A2:A17=I6)*(B2:B17=I7))).

Harun24hr, is there another formula which does not use true dates? I have encountered a hiccup in that my P+L which is reading from a table with "non-true" date headings "Jan-24", "Feb-24"... and so on and so forth is now giving me #N/A errors after I changed the headings to "true dates".
I also cannot understand why using a true date as a header in a table does not work.

@KudaMagaya what about the updated formulas I have posted. If a particular answer is not working for you then why don't you try the other answer posted.

@KudaMagaya also to make the above formula work you need to use something like this: =SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C2:F17,MONTH(C1:F1&1)<=MONTH(J6&1)),(A2:A17=I6)*(B2:B17=I7),""))

@MayukhBhattacharya I was now applying your formula, however, I seem to have encountered an #N/A error as well. I tried it on a test spreadsheet, reading from data which is not in a table, and it worked, but I've applied it to the final sheet now with dataset in a table and it's giving me an error. Could you test your formula I have pasted below, and see if its working when the data is in a table? </>
=SUM(FILTER(
XLOOKUP("Jan",C1:F1,C2:F17,0):XLOOKUP(I2,C1:F1,C2:F17,0),
(H2=A2:A17)*(H3=B2:B17),0))

@KudaMagaya i have tested using Structured References aka Tables and it still works: =SUM(FILTER(   XLOOKUP("Jan",Table1[[#Headers],[Jan]:[Apr]],Table1[[Jan]:[Apr]],0):XLOOKUP(I2,Table1[[#Headers],[Jan]:[Apr]],Table1[[Jan]:[Apr]],0),   (H2=Table1[Business Unit])*(H3=Table1[Business Activity]),0))

@MayukhBhattacharya - Thank you. Finally working. My issue was in my table that I was reading off the data from. Formula works perfect!

@KudaMagaya if the formula is working then please make sure to accept the answer here i have posted. Read here what you need to do when someone answers your question and it resolves the issues read here

There are many ways to resolve this here are few alternative ways, personally i will be using the SUMIFS() formula because it is way simpler,, efficient and easier to understand:


• Formula used in cell I3 --> Using TOCOL()+SUM()
=SUM(TOCOL(C2:F17/(H3=B2:B17)/(H2=A2:A17)/(I2=C1:F1),2))


• Formula used in cell I4 --> Using SUMIFS()+INDEX()+XMATCH()
=SUMIFS(INDEX(C2:F17,,XMATCH(I2,C1:F1)),A2:A17,H2,B2:B17,H3)


• Formula used in cell I5 --> Using CHOOSECOLS()+SUM()+XMATCH()
=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(C2:F17,XMATCH(I2,C1:F1))*(B2:B17=H3)*(H2=A2:A17))


Alternatively adding one dynamic method, if any of the Conditions are empty then also it will produce some output, may help for future references.


=LET(
     _CountBU, COUNTIF(H2,A2:A17),
     _CountBA, COUNTIF(H3,B2:B17),
     _Condition, IFS(SUM(_CountBU)=0, _CountBA, SUM(_CountBA)=0,_CountBU, 1, _CountBU*_CountBA),
     _Filter, FILTER(C2:F17, IF(SUM(_Condition)=0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(_CountBU))^0, _Condition)),
     SUM(CHOOSECOLS(_Filter,IFNA(XMATCH(I2,C1:F1),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(C1:F1))))))


Updated Formula:
Per OP Comments:

Harun24hr & Mayukh Thank you for your inputs, I understand your
formulas will give the exact figure for April, however what I am
looking for is a formula that when I choose Apr as reporting period,
the formula will add Jan, Feb, Mar & Apr giving me 331,269. If I am to
choose Mar, it'll calc from Jan - Mar giving me 252,584. I'm not sure
if we can expand and extend from this formula from this post?
stackoverflow.com/questions/78163830/… In my query, its not only the
columns that are dynamic, but also the rows.


=SUM(FILTER(
  XLOOKUP("Jan",C1:F1,C2:F17,0):XLOOKUP(I2,C1:F1,C2:F17,0),
  (H2=A2:A17)*(H3=B2:B17),0))


Another alternative way:
=SUM(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(C2:F17,
 XMATCH(TEXT(SEQUENCE(,MONTH(I2&1))*29,"mmm"),C1:F1)),
 (A2:A17=H2)*(H3=B2:B17),0))


The above updated formulas should work since as per context in the OP, that seems the months are Text Formatted.


Using TAKE

however what I am looking for is a formula that when I choose Apr as reporting period, the formula will add Jan, Feb, Mar & Apr giving me 331,269. If I am to choose Mar, it'll calc from Jan - Mar giving me 252,584.

Could you please see whether this would work? For convenience and maintenance I've added this as _calc in Name Manager.
Main logic being TAKE(_monthly_figures,,_month_index(_month)))
=LAMBDA(_data,_bu,_ba,_month,
LET(
_bu_entries, DROP(TAKE(_data,,1),1),
_ba_entries, DROP(TAKE(_data,,2),1,1),
_months, TAKE(DROP(_data,,2),1),
_month_index, LAMBDA(_name, XMATCH(_name,_months)),
_monthly_figures, DROP(_data,1,2),

IFERROR(
SUM(
--(_bu = _bu_entries) * --(_ba = _ba_entries) 
* TAKE(_monthly_figures,,_month_index(_month))), 
"Please make a selection"))

In this example, named range _data = Sheet1!$A$6:$F$22


